# Trying to install psycop on New Ubuntu and I am having compilation errors

Tags: psycopg2

Server is Ubuntu Lucid LTS

PostGreSql is 8.4

This is the error I am getting:

```
root@:~/psycopg2-2.4.2# python setup.py install build --compiler=mingw32
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
gcc -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.2 
(dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080409 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 
-DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.6 -I.
-I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server
-c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o 
-Wdeclaration-after-statement
**cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-mno-cygwin"
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-mdll"
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1**
```

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `--compiler=mingw32`.

All you need is `python setup.py install`.

Answer (score 0):

-mno-cygwin and -mdll look like options for compiling on Windows, which is odd